# Problem exporting my database sql through the terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql

I have this issue when I try to export my database with the CLI instruction  `mysqldump -u [root] -p [guru99] > [guru99].sql`

```
root@YuveSys:/home/yuve# mysqldump -u [root] -p [guru99] > [guru99].sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '[root]'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
root@YuveSys:/home/yuve#
```

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't need the `[]`'s try

```
mysqldump -u root -p guru99 > guru99.sql
```

and `guru99` should be your database name

Comment: It works without the []. I actually took it for syntax... Thanks